# Problema al aplicar estilos en Django 4.1.1

Tags: css, django, static, estilos, carga

hola gente estoy empezando en django y estoy creando una aplicacion, ya hice algunas otras a modo de practica y nunca tuve este problema por eso busco ayuda de uds.
hice este index para mi pagina subo el repositorio de github.

https://github.com/Anubis2077/index_project_django

y luego lo quise aplicar como el index de mi proyecto en django, pero al hacerlo, los estilos no se cargan de forma correcta, lo corro por liveserver y no tengo inconvenientes pero al correrlo en django los estilos simplemente no funcionan, pense que podia ser que no se cargasen mis archivos estaticos pero definitivamente si se cargan, les adjunto mi settings.py, urls.py y los links de mis archivos a ver si me pueden dar una mano, los archivos ya estan alojados en la carpeta static que se encuentra en la raiz del proyecto

index django:

```
<!-- Estilos CSS -->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lib/fullpage_js/fullpage.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" /> 


 <!-- scripts JS -->
    <script src="/lib/fullpage_js/fullpage.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/particle/particles.js-master/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #Apps
    'core.usuarios',

]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

urls.py

```
app_name= 'usuarios',

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.usuarios.urls'))
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

cualquier ayuda viene bien, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

al final lo pude resolver y no se nunca me habia pasado antes en django. pero el archivo js al llamarse main.js y el css style.css hacia conflicto y cargaba otro archivo que no tengo idea de donde venia, seguramente de alguna plantilla que viene por defecto en django, modifique los nombres de los archivos y todo bien

Answer (score 0):

Tienes puesto {% load static %} al principio de tu HTML? Si no agregas esa etiqueta no te cargará los archivos estáticos en el template.
Por otro lado, cuidado con ese STATIC_ROOT en tu settings.py, es exclusivo para producción y puede llegar a causarte problemas durante el desarrollo

Comment: hola si, al final lo pude resolver y no se nunca me habia pasado antes en django. pero el archivo js al llamarse main.js y el css style.css hacia conflicto y cargaba otro archivo que no tengo idea de donde venia, seguramente de alguna plantilla que viene por defecto en django, modifique los nombres de los archivos y todo bien